# Height of a wrapping <li>

Tags: html, css

Example: [Wrap list with images](http://danacordbutik.dk/product_info.php?manufacturers_id=&products_id=9890)

I have a **ul** with several **li**'s. Each **li** contains an image with a subtitle/text. These texts are of different lengths varying from 1 to 3 or 4 lines.

Unfortunately that makes a problem when the "line" is wrappede (please see my link).

CSS:

```
#serie-liste {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    clear: both;
    border-bottom-style:dotted;
    }

#serie-liste li {
    border: #ccc 1px solid;
    width: 150px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 20px 2px 2px 2px;
    }

#serie-liste img {
    display: block;
    border: none;
    float: none;
    clear: right;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="serie-liste">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://danacordbutik.dk/product_info.php?manufacturers_id=&amp;products_id=9843"><img width="150" height="150" src="/mediafiles/images/covers/Dist/Danacord/DACOCD%20299.jpg" alt="" />Rachmaninov: Komplette klaverkoncerter</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://danacordbutik.dk/product_info.php?manufacturers_id=&amp;products_id=9843"><img width="150" height="150" src="/mediafiles/images/covers/Dist/Danacord/DACOCD%20299.jpg" alt="" />Uge 34, 2014</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: tips: use images with proper dimension. do not use large image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A small change would be to use `display: inline-block` and remove the floats.

It could also look better if you use `vertical-align: top` or `vertical-align: middle` as the default `baseline` has unexpected results with various heights.

[Have an example!](http://jsbin.com/cubobiqekoni/1/edit)

CSS

```
#serie-liste li {
    border: #ccc 1px solid;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 20px 2px 2px 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

That gives you this:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
#serie-liste l {
    float:left; /* <<  comment this */
    display:inline-flex /* << add this */
}
```

float left will float the list to the left and you have padding and margin so maintaining the other css it would displace the next row and `inline-flex` will inline all the block with equal starting point of li block.

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could *edit your answer* and provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.

Comment: It might work with a little more development. Right now the "frames" is dissapeared and the text/subtitles doesn't wrap. Thanks for your suggestion. For now I will pick misterManSam's solution.